# Using postman to test how the Laravel will return the data

Tags: php, laravel, post, get

i am use the postman to test my laravel get and post method.
I create a route in `Route.php` `Route::get('userdata/{email}/{pw}','AndroidAppController@getUser');`

I can get the data back from the controller, my getUser function:

```
         public function getUser(){
         return 'asdasdas';
}
```

But my url cant return like: 
http://localhost:81/project/userdata?email=xxx@xxxx.com&pw=xxxxxxx 
Therefore i cannot use the postman to test how the data return, cause i going to use this as my android login function. The postman keep return me the object not found, and params cant be set because the url is not like that. The function url is 
http:localhost:81/project/userdata/xxx@xxxx.com/xxxxxx 
Any idea how to change the url to the postman support form?

Comment: You can notice that you can change the method of accessing your URL (left side of the URL) to POST

Comment: So i just change to post then ok already?

Comment: Putting your password in a querystring is a **very bad** idea

Comment: Ya, but this i gonna do for a testing.`Route::post('userdata/{email}','AndroidAppController@auth');` After that in the postman, i just need to pass the param to it right?

Answer (score 1):

Your application does not support `GET` parameters. You can either add another route to handle get parameters in your app:

```
Route::get('userdata','AndroidAppController@getUserQueryString')
```

Where `getUserQueryString` pass `GET` parameters to `getUser`

Or use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^email=(.*)&pw=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/project/userdata$  /project/userdata/%1/%2 [L,R=301]
```

First option is better, second is quicker.

Comment: Ok, i got try one which is dingo, is that a better choice for open API? And to perform the CRUD function?

Comment: It is very opinion-based, and depends what your API is doing. For RESTish ones, the rule of thumb is url defines the resource, query string defines optional parameters. It may worth to read http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html